# Randomising ListView content in FlutterFlow

Tags: flutterflow

does anyone know how to randomise a firebase database and display it in flutterflow listview? I tried implementing a shuffle method in a custom function but it still wouldn't shuffle the content.

A step-by-step would be much help if it's alright.

Much appreciated if anyone can help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.